# Future payment with iOS Stripe SDK

Tags: ios, automation, stripe-payments, payment

Using the iOS SDK for Stripe, can we do the following

1. Create a customer profile where the customer id can be sent and stored to the backend
2. Add, edit, delete credit cards to the customer profile
3. Card can be charged automatically from the backend

Note that, once the user make a payment via stripe, we ask them to allow auto-payment next time the balance goes below a certain level. So, it is not periodic subscription. But it is a permission in advance, to charge later.

For a single payment, the SDK takes the card info and provides the token. Token passed to server where the payment is finally process. This looks very nice and secured.

I do not want to store the card info in the iOS app, also not in server. But does stripe take the responsibility to store it and allow the backend to charge it later? I need a way so that server can communicate with stripe with a unique id and amount, so that stripe accepts the request and make the payment.

Comment: Yes  we can..Once the payment done, the account will be saved in the Stripe account.. From there you can get the Customer ID and save in your server.. Actually you no need to save their card details locally, but only the customer ID which is returned from Stripe,

Comment: Thanks @Bharathi. The iOS SDK does not seem to have create/retrieve card/customer function. I mean something like the createTokenWithCard method. So should I use the REST APIs to create customer and to add card ? As they documented here - https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customers

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for webservice to your webservice developer which can make APIs to create customers in stripe account and store its customer_id in database so for next all payment you can make payment using customer id. Stripe will store card details in its database so no need to store card details at our side.